# how can i get the source address of an uploaded file in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need the actual location of the file that i have just uploaded via a file upload control in asp.net. I've tried using

```
string fileName = Path.GetFullPath(fUpldGetDoc.PostedFile.FileName);
```

but this returns

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\angel from montegomery.txt
```

but I need the actual location of the file i.e,

```
e:\angel from montegomery.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can remember, this is not a portable feature in most browsers.

IE7 might (?) be able to support it, but most other browsers (FireFox, Opera, Chrome) seem to say that the filename is supported, but the path is hidden for privacy/security reasons. (IIRC some browsers will even 'make up' some noticeably bogus path so you will clearly see that it has been replaced for security reasons)

I don't currently have the time to quote a source on that, but for now this is my info

**EDIT**: Information outlining the [behavior across browsers when using this property](http://tdryan.blogspot.com/2011/08/httppostedfilefilename-beware.html).

Comment: @AaronMcIver: thanks a bunch for making my hint into an answer

Answer (score 3):

[HttpPostedFile.FileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.filename.aspx) should provide you with the FQ path of the file on the client's machine.

```
HttpFileCollection MyFileColl = Request.Files;
HttpPostedFile MyPostedFile = MyFileColl.Get(0);
String MyFileName = MyPostedFile.FileName;
```

Keep in mind that the [browser can return whatever it wants](http://tdryan.blogspot.com/2011/08/httppostedfilefilename-beware.html), opting to hide portions of the path if it so desires.

All in all the actual path on disk is irrelevant since you have the data in the `HttpPostedFile` as well as the name.